# set different login forms for different browsers?

Tags: php, html

Can someone please help me. i am having difficulties getting a form to display and behave correctly in  firefox only. every other browser works fine.

But i wanted to try and set a rule in php to say if chrome, ie etc do do this and if firefox do that.

i have made an attempt of this below, when using ie and chrome etc the login form comes up as expected but when using firefox there is no login form displayed. no error message.

```
<div id="login">
    <?
    if (preg_match('/Chrome|Opera|Safari|MSIE 8.0/', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) { ?>

      <?php
        if (!logged_in()) {
            ?>

      <form id="myform" action="login.php" method="post" class="loginform">

    Email
      <input type="text" name="email" maxlength="30" />

    Password
    <input type="password" name="password" maxlength="30" />

    <input type="image" src="../PTB1/assets/img/icons/loginarrow1.png" name="submit" class="loginbutton" />

                </form>


               <?php
        }
        if (logged_in()) {
            ?>


                 Logged in as, <?php echo $_SESSION['email'] ?>. <a href="dashboard.php">Dashboard</a>, <a href="logout.php">Logout</a> |&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<div class="login_settings" id="login_settings"></div>
    <?php
        }

    else if (preg_match('/Firefox/', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) { 


        if (!logged_in()) {
            ?>

      <form action="login.php" rel="shadowbox;height=300;width=500" method="post" >

                    <div class="row email">
                        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" value="<?php echo htmlentities($email); ?>" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="row password">
                        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" value="<?php echo htmlentities($email); ?>" />
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login >"  />
                </form>


               <?php
        }
        if (logged_in()) {
            ?>


                 Logged in as, <?php echo $_SESSION['email'] ?>. <a href="dashboard.php">Dashboard</a>, <a href="logout.php">Logout</a> |&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<div class="login_settings" id="login_settings"></div> 

    <?  


    } } }
    ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: That's kind of the wrong approach, I suggest fixing it for Firefox too, rather than creating an hacked version for each browser

Comment: ^ 100% agree - this is the absolute wrong approach for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding from your code is that you are trying to detect if the browser is Firefox just so you can use the `placeholder` attribute and other HTML5 form features.

Not only is this is horrible idea (IE10 and Chrome both support `placeholder`, and I'm sure Opera does too), but it's an inappropriate use of the `placeholder` attribute anyway.

Instead, just use this form:

```
<form action="login.php" method="post">
  <div class="row email">
    Email:
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="john.smith@example.com" />
  </div>
  <div class="row password">
    Password:
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
  </div>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login &gt;" />
</form>
```

After all, there is no harm in putting an attribute that may not be supported, it just gets ignored.